# '80-'90s horror movie about a woman falling in love with a male humanoid robot

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I'm having a hard time finding an old movie from '80s or '90s.
It might be a B-movie, I don't remember it having any big stars in it.
It is English-language.

It involves a lonely woman ordering an humanoid robot, not designed for relationships but eventually they hook up (sorry for the spoiler). The robot is 100% humanoid, it doesn't look like metal or anything.

The robot is not designed for relationships. The protagonist alters the settings, and makes the robot available to love. The company responsible for the robot says the robot might become dangerous. He eventually becomes so and tries to assassinate the protagonist.

It used to be broadcast on HBO, I think.

Any clues?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please take a look at the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and then [edit] your question to include any further details you can think to add. And don't worry about posting spoilers. The more details you can add, the better.

Comment: You've got the [horror] tag and "horror" in the title, what about it was particularly horrifying?

Comment: @LogicDictates Thanks I did update it accordingly

Comment: @fez I didn't mean to spoil the movie, but here is why:
The robot is not design for relationships. the protagonists messes up with the settings, and make the robot available to love.
The company responsible for the robot says the robot might become dangerous.
He eventually becomes so and tries to assassinate the protagonists.

Comment: Please add as many spoilers as you can remember, the more information you add the more likely someone will know what you're looking for.

Comment: @fez That's as much as I remember.
The robot is 100% humanoid, it doesn't look like metal or anything.

Comment: Could it be Twisted Tales E03 Directly From My Heart To You https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rcRPwa9BC8k ?

Comment: If this were a book, we could consider Asimov's 1983 novel _[The Robots of Dawn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Robots_of_Dawn)_ a candidate.

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi
That's not it, thank you though! I think both the protagonist and robot had brown hair

Comment: @Spencer Thanks! getting close but it was definetly a movie

Answer (score 13):

This could be [The Companion](https://imdb.com/title/tt0109464/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl), a direct to video movie from 1994.

[image: screener]

> Writer catches her boyfriend cheating on her. Infuriated, she buys an
> android companion and takes him with her to a remote cabin in the
> woods to keep her company as she writes. She starts a romance with
> him, which turns into a nightmare.

The plot points that match the question include the woman buying the male android, and playing with his programming to be a better boyfriend. Some of this comes in the form of playing with the 'settings', but then she actually changes the programming to make him more random/spontaneous which results in the android beating up her ex and another guy who makes advances, before really going crazy.

Reprogramming:
[image]

Gillian Tanner:

[image]

Android:

[image]